# How to add bootstrap template in django app

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I want to add bootstrap template in my django app. I have downloaded it and kept in my static folder, then added its path in setting.py file as-

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = '/home/dc/my_django_apps/mutech_website/mutech/static/'
```

index.html of template is-

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Freelancer - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - Uses Bootswatch Flatly Theme: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/freelancer.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

but still its not working. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [configure the static files app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files), in setting.py by adding this setting

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and make sure you have all your static files/folders inside a folder called static in the root or in static folder inside your app but make sure to run [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) command, then reference JS file from static files please use this syntax

```
<script src="{% static 'js/classie.js' %}"></script>
```

and for linking the CSS:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hello thanx... but i actually want to add a template of bootstrap from startbootstrap.com .Bootstrap is working in my project.

Comment: Can you please add how you are linking and reference your CSS and JS files in your template?

Comment: Hey @Emad Mokhtar i have added my index.html in question

Comment: If you put all your static files in on static folder, no need to run the command.
collectstatic commd collects the static files from all installed apps and copies them to the STATICFILES_STORAGE. http://django-staticfiles.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.1/commands.html

Comment: hey @Emad Mokhtar, i have linked all static files in the manner u told, but i am getting the error -                   "GET /static/bootstrap_template/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59

Answer (score 0):

You will need 3 variables in your settings.py:

```
# Alias that will be written in the source code
STATIC_URL = '/public/'

# The actual folder where static files will be collected
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

# Location of folders that will be added to static folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "folder_one", "folder_two", "static"),
)
```

After this, you'll need to run the command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

that will copy all static files to the STATIC_ROOT.

After this, you can use the static files in the template. Just add the tag to the template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

and use the static tag:

```
{% static 'folder_one/folder_two/path_to_static' %}
```

You can also use

```
... src="/public/folder_one/folder_two/path_to_static" ...
```

but if you want to change the alias one day, you'll have to change all of them... so, the first option is much better.

You'll have to check the static folder to see what path you'll have to use.

And django will write something like this

```
'/public/folder_one/folder_two/path_to_static'
```

When you make this work, have a look at [bower](http://bower.io/) and [bower-installer](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer)

The first will download all packages that you need with a single command. The second will put all the files you need in a specific folder. This is quite good because you don't have to download one by one.

bower.json example

```
{
  "name": "your_project_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "authors": [
     "you Name <your@email>"
  ],
  "license": "License type",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
     "jquery": "latest",
     "bootstrap": "latest"
  },
  "install": {
     "path": "where/do/you/want/your/files"
  }
}
```

Just add more dependencies and you're done. Then check bower-installer. It will copy only the files you need to a directory and not the whole source code for each package. when you're done you can remove the bower folder if you want and leave only the bower-installer folder.